# Why post-decrements operator in the following C code is not working as desired? (to have the value of 7)

Tags: c, operators, decrement, operands

Why post-decrements operator in the following C code is not working as desired? (to have the value of 7). Knowing that it is not an undefined behaviour.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int a = 8, r;
    r = (a==8) || (a--);
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression `(a==8) || (a--);` since `(a==8)` is already true hence rest of the OR condition is not evaluated.